# ¿Cómo agrego option de un select desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

He estado un buen rato tratando de averiguar como puede insertar código `html` en un `select`, les explico.

Estoy realizando un *obligatorio* el cual me pide ingresar un *rubro*, a su vez ese *rubro* se debe de guardar en un `table` y que quede guardado en un `select` de otra `div`.

También tengo problemas que al dar al *botón añadir*, se me recarga y no muestra nada.

Agradezco su aportes.

Código en `JS`

```
function PushArray() {
    var checkRubro = document.getElementById("ButtonRubro");
    var NombreRubro = document.getElementById("NameRubro").value;
    if (NombreRubro != '') {
        Rubro = { "ID": ArrayRubro.length + 1, 'NombreDeRubro': NombreRubro, 'Habilitado': checkRubro.checked };
        ArrayRubro.push(Rubro);
    }
    TablaDeDatos()

}
function TablaDeDatos() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";

    var tablehtml = "<table> <thead> <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Rubro</th>   <th>Estado</th> </thead> <tbody>";
    for (i = 0; i < ArrayRubro.length; i++) {
        tablehtml += "<tr> <td>" + ArrayRubro[i]["ID"] + "</td> <td>" + ArrayRubro[i]["NombreDeRubro"] + ArrayRubro[i]["Habilitado"] + "</td> <td>";

        table.innerHTML = tablehtml;
    }
}

function AgregarOpt() {
    var SelectRubro = document.getElementById("SelectToRubro");
    SelectRubro.innerHTML = "";


    for (i = 0; i < ArrayRubro.length; i++) {
        var OptionsHtml = "<option >" + ArrayRubro[i]['NombreDeRubro'] + "</option>";


        SelectRubro.innerHTML = OptionsHtml;

    }

}

    <div id="CuerpoGeneral">
        <div id="table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Rubro</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="Rubros" class="pepe">

            <h2>Agregar un rubro</h2>
            <hr>

            <form class="FormulariodeR">
                <div class="CSSForm">
                    <label for="NameRubro">
                        <p>Rubro</p>
                    </label>

                    <input id="NameRubro" class="field" placeholder="Ingrese un nuevo rubro">

                </div>

                <div class="CSSForm">
                    <label for="ButtonRubro">
                        <p>Habilitar</p>
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ButtonRubro">
                </div>

                <div id="error"></div>
                <button class="Boton" onclick="PushArray(), AgregarOpt()">Añadir</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="Disciplina" class="pepe">
            <h2>Disciplina </h2>
            <hr>
            <form>
                <div class="CSSForm">
                    <label for="SelectToRubro">
                        <p>Rubro</p>
                    </label>
                    <select id="SelectToRubro">


                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="CSSForm">
                    <label for="NameDisciplina">
                        <p>Disciplina</p>
                    </label>
                    <input id="NameDisciplina" class="field" placeholder="Ingrese una nueva disciplina">

                </div>

                <div class="CSSForm">
                    <label for="ButtonDisciplina">
                        <p>Habilitar</p>
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ButtonDisciplina">
                </div>
                <button class="Boton" onclick="">Añadir</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Puedes compartir el html?

Comment: Les dejo el HTML

Comment: Para qué es el checkbox?